# Update cell with new value if its a duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I have a table of plants, some of which share the same common name. If the plant shares the common name with other plants, I'd like to add the genus and species in parenthesise after the common name to avoid confusion. Of note, not all plants have a common name.

To test it out I created a `common_name2` column.

I wrote the following script:

```
UPDATE `plants` 
    SET `common_name2` = CONCAT(`common_name`, ' (', `genus`, ' ', `species`, ')') 
WHERE `common_name` != '' 
GROUP BY `common_name`  
HAVING COUNT(`common_name`) > 1
```

But I'm getting the following error and I can't figure out:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near `GROUP BY common_name HAVING COUNT('common_name') > 1` at line 1

Comment: Just a suggestion. You could try and create a SQL Fiddle with some sample data using http://sqlfiddle.com/. Would be easier for others to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that this way: your `GROUP BY` don't go along with your `SET CONCAT`.

Here is how to do it:

```
UPDATE `plants` 
SET `common_name2` = CONCAT(`common_name`, ' (', `genus`, ' ', `species`, ')') 
WHERE `common_name` IN (
    select `common_name`
    FROM (select * from `plants`) plants
    WHERE `common_name` != '' 
    GROUP BY `common_name`  
    HAVING COUNT(`common_name`) > 1
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f47d/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE plants
    (`id` int, `common_name` varchar(50), `common_name2` varchar(50), `genus` varchar(9), `species` varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO plants
    (`id`, `common_name`, `common_name2`, `genus`, `species`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Roses', NULL, 'Rosa', 'Hulthemia'),
    (2, 'Roses', NULL, 'Rosa', 'Hesperrhodos'),
    (3, 'Roses', NULL, 'Rosa', 'Platyrhodon'),
    (4, 'Roses', NULL, 'Rosa', 'Rosa'),
    (5, 'Petunia', NULL, 'Petunia', 'axillaris'),
    (6, 'Petunia', NULL, 'Petunia', 'integrifolia'),
    (7, 'Cardinal', NULL, 'Lobelia', 'cardinalis'),
    (8, 'Anthurium', NULL, 'Anthurium', 'andraeanum')
;

UPDATE `plants` 
SET `common_name2` = CONCAT(`common_name`, ' (', `genus`, ' ', `species`, ')') 
WHERE `common_name` IN (
    select `common_name`
    FROM (select * from `plants`) plants
    WHERE `common_name` != '' 
    GROUP BY `common_name`  
    HAVING COUNT(`common_name`) > 1
)
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from plants
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77f47d/1/0)**:

```
| id | common_name |                   common_name2 |     genus |      species |
|----|-------------|--------------------------------|-----------|--------------|
|  1 |       Roses |         Roses (Rosa Hulthemia) |      Rosa |    Hulthemia |
|  2 |       Roses |      Roses (Rosa Hesperrhodos) |      Rosa | Hesperrhodos |
|  3 |       Roses |       Roses (Rosa Platyrhodon) |      Rosa |  Platyrhodon |
|  4 |       Roses |              Roses (Rosa Rosa) |      Rosa |         Rosa |
|  5 |     Petunia |    Petunia (Petunia axillaris) |   Petunia |    axillaris |
|  6 |     Petunia | Petunia (Petunia integrifolia) |   Petunia | integrifolia |
|  7 |    Cardinal |                         (null) |   Lobelia |   cardinalis |
|  8 |   Anthurium |                         (null) | Anthurium |   andraeanum |
```